# How to Decode/Encode PDF XRef Stream?

Tags: pdf, stream, gzip, zlib, cross-reference

Not able to decode following `xref` stream in PDF using zlib:

```
3012 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Columns 4/Predictor 12>>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[<E98C07C3C054134DE4A6A2C246B76C19><E2399F34D43541DC9245F219398B2E97>]/Index[2573 1 2962 1 2967 2 3004 9]/Info 2573 0 R/Length 58/Prev 1365436/Root 2575 0 R/Size 3013/Type/XRef/W[1 3 0]>>stream
hﬁbby<çâÅÅiê‡èbb|#.œÙ_‰U    êÀ$òù@≤m Æ,ê`TÉ±ò∫A¨^Ä��l�  �
endstream
endobj
```

Can anybody help me to decode it?

Comment: When you pasted the binary code into this question, the binary stream got corrupted. The stream should consist of 58 bytes, yet I count only 53 characters in the snippet you pasted. If you are asking people to decode those 53 characters, they can't because they need 58 bytes, not 53 characters.

Comment: Funny... depending on the copied-text I use for my 'counting command' `echo '<copied-text>' | wc -c` I count a lenght of either 89 or 94 bytes. (I copied from the source Markdown or from the rendered HTML.) -- However, of course, Bruno's comment is spot-on: you cannot copy binary bytes into a web-based text editor and assume they survive this treatment unscathed... (Bruno concluded correctly from the `Length 58` entry in the pasted code that we should expect the number of 58 bytes.)

Comment: I can share the pdf file, could you please provide your email address?

Comment: I amfighting myself with that at the moment. Good hints are provided here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/664902. I managed to decode the deflate part but decoding further the PNG predictors yields strange results for my examples. But the hints how to proceed are there